# Android, if/else construct always fails (Compiler fails to read changes)

Tags: android, if-statement, compiler-errors, handler, intentservice

What i'm trying to do should be pretty simple, i'm calling an **IntentService to check periodically in background if the current time is before or after a specified time** (passed as Extras in the intent from the MainActivity) and get a notification when it happens.

In Thread's run() method i get an instance of the current time and use it as comparison to the previously specified one in an **if/else** construct, before re-running the Thread. 
The problem is that it always go for "else" even if the current time is after the other one. This problem is just too strange, can anyone explain me where is the error?

Here is my IntentService class:

```
public class MyCheck extends IntentService {

int hour = 0; int minute = 0;
int i = 0;
private static final String TAG = "Check";
int hourNow;
int minuteNow;

Handler handler = new Handler();


public MyCheck() {
    super(MyCheck.class.getName());
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.w(TAG, "Service Started!");
    hour = intent.getIntExtra("hour", 0);
    minute = intent.getIntExtra("minute", 0);

    Log.w(TAG, "Step 1 ");
    Thread runnable = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
  /* do what you need to do */
            Log.w(TAG, "Step 2 ");
  /* get current time */          
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             hourNow = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
             minuteNow = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        //HERE, IT SEEMS THAT IT'S ALWAYS BEFORE hour AND minute

            if(hourNow > hour || (hourNow == hour && minuteNow > minute)) {
                //SEND 
                Log.w(TAG, "RUN ");

                Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                broadcast.setAction(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                sendBroadcast(broadcast);


                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
            else {
                //NOTHING
                i++;
                Log.w(TAG, "NOT YET " + i);
            }
      //REPEAT EVERY 6 SECONDS
            try {
                sleep(6000);
                handler.post(this);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    runnable.start();

}

}
```

**EDIT**

I've found the trivial problem as you can see in my answer below.
If someone wants to complete the answer with some more information about the problems that can occur during the building process they will be apreciated. TIA

Comment: I think the problem lies in the value the you obtain from the `Intent`. Could you add logs to log `hour`, `minute`, `hourNow`, `minuteNow`. Log these immediately before the `if` statement. Then post the log here.

Comment: @Henry Tried the same code this morning and now works... Logs show the correct  hours and minutes... it's not the first time it happens, i guess Android Studio sometimes flips. Thank you for the comment anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to this was to wait and reboot Windows. The code wasn't flawed after all, it's just something on the building process that needed some time to tell the compiler that the error wasn't there: maybe there was a copy in cache of a past error that was still taken in account, i'm not sure.

Maybe you can add some information to my last statement, posting an answer or a commenting about it.